# How Can I Solve Encoding Problem while Using Kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, encoding, kivy, codec

I am very new to establishing GUI's and Kivy, I am using Python 3. I have tried to run a basic code which I have found online but there seems to be an encoding issue which I couldn't solve. My code goes as:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label  


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = "A")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

The error message I get is this:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0131' in position 280: character maps to undefined

Complete Traceback:

````
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2a8b8f5ea334> in <module>
     12 
     13 
---> 14 MyApp().run()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py in run(self)
    827             self.load_config()
    828             self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
--> 829             root = self.build()
    830             if root:
    831                 self.root = root

<ipython-input-3-2a8b8f5ea334> in build(self)
      9 
     10     def build(self):
---> 11         return Label(text='Hello world')
     12 
     13 

kivy\_event.pyx in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__cinit__()

kivy\properties.pyx in kivy.properties.Property.link()

kivy\properties.pyx in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.init_storage()

kivy\properties.pyx in kivy.properties.Property.init_storage()

kivy\properties.pyx in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.convert()

kivy\properties.pyx in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.parse_str()

kivy\properties.pyx in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.parse_list()

kivy\properties.pyx in kivy.properties.dpi2px()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py in __get__(self, inst, cls)
    503         if inst is None:
    504             return self
--> 505         retval = self.func(inst)
    506         setattr(inst, self.func.__name__, retval)
    507         return retval

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\metrics.py in dpi(self)
    172         # for all other platforms..
    173         from kivy.base import EventLoop
--> 174         EventLoop.ensure_window()
    175         return EventLoop.window.dpi
    176 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py in ensure_window(self)
    121         '''Ensure that we have a window.
    122         '''
--> 123         import kivy.core.window  # NOQA
    124         if not self.window:
    125             Logger.critical('App: Unable to get a Window, abort.')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py in <module>
   2066 if platform == 'linux':
   2067     window_impl += [('x11', 'window_x11', 'WindowX11')]
-> 2068 Window = core_select_lib('window', window_impl, True)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py in core_select_lib(category, llist, create_instance, base, basemodule)
    101         'debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or '
    102         'change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to '
--> 103         'identify potential causes\n{1}'.format(category.capitalize(), err))
    104 
    105 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in critical(self, msg, *args, **kwargs)
   1428         """
   1429         if self.isEnabledFor(CRITICAL):
-> 1430             self._log(CRITICAL, msg, args, **kwargs)
   1431 
   1432     fatal = critical

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info, extra, stack_info)
   1517         record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args,
   1518                                  exc_info, func, extra, sinfo)
-> 1519         self.handle(record)
   1520 
   1521     def handle(self, record):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in handle(self, record)
   1527         """
   1528         if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
-> 1529             self.callHandlers(record)
   1530 
   1531     def addHandler(self, hdlr):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in callHandlers(self, record)
   1589                 found = found + 1
   1590                 if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
-> 1591                     hdlr.handle(record)
   1592             if not c.propagate:
   1593                 c = None    #break out

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py in handle(self, record)
    903             self.acquire()
    904             try:
--> 905                 self.emit(record)
    906             finally:
    907                 self.release()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py in emit(self, message)
    245                 self._write_message(_message)
    246 
--> 247         self._write_message(message)
    248 
    249 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py in _write_message(self, record)
    216                 stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
    217         else:
--> 218             stream.write(fs % msg)
    219         stream.flush()
    220 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in encode(self, input, final)
     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
     20 
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0131' in position 280: character maps to <undefined>

```
````

Comment: Are you sure it is complaining about thee "A"? A unicode '\u0131' is a lowercase 'i' without a dot (actually looks like a small '1').

Comment: Please post the complete traceback. It will say exactly where the error is.

Comment: Are you using python2? If so, try using python3

Comment: Have U solved the problem? If yes, pls post solution here.